# How to make an angular popup?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, modal-dialog

I want to create a angular dialog or modal popup.when I press a button. In that popup I am exhibiting a form.

My html code for that button:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary"  type="submit" (click)="setting()" style="border-radius:40px;margin-left: 15px;"
color="primary"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

My html code for the form I wish to show in the popup:

```
<div style="margin-left: 50px;margin-right: 80%;margin-top: 1%; width: 100%;">
    <h3>
        Type Form
    </h3>
    <div>
        <form>
            <table>
                <div>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <mat-form-field>
                                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                                <input matInput placeholder="Name"  autocomplete="off" required>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                </div>
            </table>
      
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Kindly tell me if there is any solution. Pls add the click() in ts.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the contents of the dialog in an ng-template tag and set a reference like that

```
<ng-template #dialogRef>your form</ng-template>
```

there is a good example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-mat-dialog?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) :