# Is there a way to button in a table that open a card that covers the whole table

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have created a table with a button that opens a card when clicked. However the card only covers a portion of the table when I want it to cover the whole table taking up the size of the content in the card. How can I acheive this

I have tried using class cointainer to wrap the table and card and a also css to style the card but nothing works.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
      <table class= "table" >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
            <td><button (click)="toggleCard()">View</button></td>
            <div class="card" *ngIf="showCard" style="width: 50rem;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card 
   subtitle</h6>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
          </div>
        </div>

and css:.container{
    position:relative;
    background-color: black;
}
.card{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Can you also include your code for this? Without that, it's hard to tell what you're doing and what would be useful for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I correctly got what you are trying to achieve but it seems like you want to create a pop-up that will be shown above your table. Please, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674405/how-to-make-an-angular-popup), there is an answer with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-mat-dialog?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) link, maybe it's what you're looking for

**Edited**

If you don't use Angular material you can do it yourself by using a separate service and component. Something like [this project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7lmkx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).
A small explanation:

1. There is `pop-up.service.ts` with BehaviorSubject which controls when the pop-up will be open
2. Then there is `pop-up.component` which is subscribed to `BehaviorSubject` value and displays based on it(it's a simple ngIf that controls if it's being displayed). + some scss to make it look like a pop-up

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I want to create a pop up. However I did not use Mat tables and dialog box but Bootsrap table and card.

Comment: @GraceWangari, I've updated the answer with another way to do pop-ups, please, take a look. Hope it would suit your needs more :)